# How to visualiize logaritmic scale in levelplot

Tags: r, plot, levelplot

I'm new on R and I tried to plot my matrix with levelplot function.

In order to have better visualization, I need to have a logarithmic
scale of colour scale. 
I have x, y, z like following:

```
head(x)
#[1] "2018-01-31 11:01:43 UTC" "2018-01-31 11:08:29 UTC" "2018-01-31 11:16:14 UTC"
#[4] "2018-01-31 11:23:59 UTC" "2018-01-31 11:31:44 UTC" "2018-01-31 11:39:29 UTC"

head(y)
#      [,1]
#[1,] 10.27
#[2,] 11.21
#[3,] 12.24
#[4,] 13.36
#[5,] 14.60
#[6,] 15.94

head(z)
#           [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]     [,5]      [,6]      [,7]      
#[1,]  253.1243  884.0269 7962.6024 3920.2461 885.9349  884.6629 1139.0592 
#[2,] 4303.7484 1138.4232 1771.8698 1518.1096 505.5489  758.1008 1139.0592  
#[3,] 2024.9941 2024.9941  758.7368 1518.7456 885.9349 1392.8194 1139.0592  
#[4,]  379.3684 1139.0592  379.6228  253.1243 379.6228 1519.3816 1139.6952  
#[5,]  379.0504  126.1169  126.3077  633.0014 252.9335 1265.6213    0.0000  
#[6,]    0.0000    0.0000  126.4349  126.3713 379.6228    0.0000  126.3077
```

and the code I used:

```
 library(lattice
 library(openair)
 attach(x)

    x<-as.POSIXct(date, format="%YY-%MM-%DD %HH:%MM")
    y<-matrix(c(10.27,11.21,12.24,13.36,14.6,15.94,17.42,19.3,20.8,22.74,24.86,27.19,29.75,32.56,35.65,39.06,42.8,46.93,51.49,56.53,62.12,68.31,75.19,82.85,91.4,100.97,111.72,123.81,137.48,152.97,170.61,190.77,213.9,240.58,271.46,307.34,349.21,398.2,455.7,523.3,602.93,696.85,807.86,938.85,1093.95), ncol=1, byrow=TRUE)

    attach(z)
   z<-matrix(c(`10.27`,`11.21`,`12.24`,`13.36`,`14.6`,`15.94`,`17.420000000000002`,`19.03`,`20.8`,`22.74`,`24.86`,`27.19`,`29.75`,`32.56`,`35.65`,`39.06`,`42.8`,`46.93`,`51.49`,`56.53`,`62.12`,`68.31`,`75.19`,`82.85`,`91.4`,`100.97`,`111.72`,`123.81`,`137.47999999999999`,`152.97`,`170.61`,`190.77`,`213.9`,`240.58`,`271.45999999999998`,`307.33999999999997`,`349.21`,`398.2`,`455.7`,`523.29999999999995`,`602.92999999999995`,`696.85`,`807.76`,`938.85`,`1093.95`), ncol=45, byrow=T)

    levelplot(z, aspect="fill",col.regions=rainbow(30),row.values=x,column.values=y,scales=list(x=list(rot=45)),interpolate=TRUE, xlab="Data", ylab="Diametro (nm)")
```

Could anyone help me, please?
Thanks.